# BigTable: Can two column qualifiers from different column family have same name?

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

My questions is:
"Can two column qualifiers from different column family have same name?"

I went through Google Documentation but couldn't get my answer:
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design#column_families_and_column_qualifiers

I have a scenario where I am storing cumulative/avg/min/max  of some measurements (pressure, temperature, volume and many more).

I am planning to store data:

```
col-family:col:value

cum:pressure:<value>

avg:temperature:<value>

avg:pressure:<value>
```

Its just an example above. Now from the example first and third entry has different column family but same column name. Is this allowed in BigTable?

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Overview of Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview#empty-cells) documentation, in Bigtable the rows are basically a collection of key/value entries, where the keys are composed of a combination of the column family and the column qualifier. So as long as you don’t have the same qualifier inside the same family you are good to go.